# How to I suppress reporting of each test in QuickCheck, without suppressing summary output?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

In QuickCheck, is there a way to suppress the

```
(0 tests)         (1 test)        (2 tests)         (3 tests)         (4 tests)  ...
```

output without suppressing the summary

```
+++ OK, passed 500 tests.
```

output?

I've tried setting [`chatty = False`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Test.html#g:1), but that suppresses both.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are calling quickCheck so that it displays that other output? When I run http://lpaste.net/145061 I only see the summary line.

Comment: Can you give more details? What's you Arbitrary instance for MyType?

Comment: @ErikR: Sorry, I was wrong. I see this no matter what I do (or what my type is).

Comment: @ErikR: You see only the summary line, because QuickCheck is too fast and your terminal understands `\b` or similar measurements taken by QuickCheck to overwrite the previous count of tests. Test a property that takes some time, or use something like `sleep n x = unsafePerformIO (threadDelay (n * 10^6) >> return x)` to see the counter.

Comment: @ErikR: Interestingly, I don't see this in all consoles. So perhaps it's just something to do with stdout and stderr being combined somehow by my IDE's console.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Some IDEs don't support overwriting previous text. QuickCheck flushes all text that's still in buffers, and then tries to move the cursor back via `\b`. However, that needs the terminal's support for moving the cursor back which simple file streamers usually lack. Instead, you end up with a stray `0x08` byte in your output (which often gets filtered by viewers or shown as strange symbol/space).

Comment: run `runhaskell tests.hs > out 2> err` and `ls -l err` will show you that a lot has been written to stderr. To actually see the contents of `err` use `od err` or `hexdump err`.

Comment: @Zeta: That could be it. I'll try it out in some other settings to see what happens.

Comment: @Zeta: Sure enough: in Apple Terminal it all gets overwritten and all I see in the end is the summary output. I think that's going to be the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're only interested in the summary output, you could use `quickCheckWithResult` together with `chatty = False`:

```
silentQuickCheck :: Testable prop => prop -> IO () 
silentQuickCheck p = quickCheckWithResult stdArgs { chatty = False } p >>= putStr . output
```

Example:

```
main = do
   putStrLn "Even: "
   silentQuickCheck even
   putStrLn "Odd: "
   silentQuickCheck odd
   putStrLn "ID Eq: "
   silentQuickCheck $ \n -> n == n
```

Output:

```
Even:
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 6 tests):
3
Odd: 
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 1 test):
0
ID Eq:
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

However, on terminals/outputs that move the cursor backwards on`\b` (ASCII backspace), the test count (`(xx tests)`) gets rewritten over and over again, so this is only necessary if your output/terminal doesn't acknowledge `\b` in this sense.